# Identifying content/image type from NSImage

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have an `NSImage` instance and I'd like to identify the type of image it is (JPG, PNG, GIF, etc.).

Is the original format of the image preserved and possible to retrieve somehow?

**EDIT:** 
Answers in other questions mention using `CGImageSource`. However, there does not seem to be a way of extracting the original data from the `NSImage` - only `TIFFRepresentation`, which will always return the `TIFF` image type via `CGImageSource`.

**EDIT 2:**
I think my suspicions may be true in that `NSImage` does not maintain the original format of the image. Everything is converted to bitmap representation. Therefore it is not possible to retrieve the original format without keeping track of it yourself. See similar answer from iOS equivalent: [Detect whether an UIImage is PNG or JPEG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216696/detect-whether-an-uiimage-is-png-or-jpeg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i find the file type after loading NSImage withContentsOfFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590003/how-can-i-find-the-file-type-after-loading-nsimage-withcontentsoffile)

Comment: @the4kman see edit on why that may not be the correct answer.

Comment: The answer is correct: "NSImage doesn't keep that information".

Comment: @Willeke The answer says `CGImageSourceRef` can retrieve that information which is incorrect - the information is not retrievable once it is passed into `NSImage`.